# Locked for editing issues when looping through all files in SharePoint folder

Tags: vba, excel, loops, sharepoint

I have built a sub in VBA Excel to loop through a mapped SharePoint drive (`I:\`), open, refresh all connections, save, and close each file in a given folder path as shown:

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
    myPath = "I:\" 'Mapped sharepoint drive.
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings
myExtension = "*.xlsm"
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
 Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
'Refresh all workbook connections
wb.RefreshAll
'Wait until refreshed to save
DoEvents

'Save and Close Workbook
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
 MsgBox "'All workbooks Updated!'"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It works well but runs into issues when a user has a file locked for editing on the SharePoint server. When a file is locked for editing a warning message pops up on my local machine stating the file is locked for editing, stalling the VBA until I deal with it manually or exit the subroutine. Disabling alerts in VBA does not prevent the message-boxes from stalling the cycle. I have read about others using functions to check if the file is locked before running the code but I am having a hard time blending the two concepts together so that the sub checks each file before it attempts to open them. [Checking if file is locked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641474/need-help-on-opening-another-workbook-on-the-network)

I also looked at [Case 0 Case 70](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open) but I am not skilled enough at the moment to integrate the two concepts. The dream would be first to check if a file is locked for editing, skip to the next free file if the current file is locked and if a file is free to open, refresh all connections, save and close the file before continuing on to the next file in the folder-path.

Comment: I thought SharePoint files had to be checked out before saving changes to them.  I'm not at work so I can't test this right now.  Have you checked if the last saved date and time on workbooks that have not displayed the "locked for editing" message have actually been updated?

Comment: Yes I can update sharepoint files that are not locked for editing. They open, update and save back to the server with a new timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to wrap the actions in a try catch,  assuming the error thrown is an exception,  do this:

```
try
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    'Refresh all workbook connections
    wb.RefreshAll
    'Wait until refreshed to save
    DoEvents

    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
catch

End try

'Get next file name
myFile = Dir
```

Comment: try..catch isn't a VBA construct - I think it may be .net

Comment: it is .NET   however i thought they had ported that across to later versions of excel?   my mistake.